# How i can extend my jsx element using construction like <extendFunc.div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props, framer-motion

Frankly speaking, it is even difficult to formulate the question, since did not work with it before. Several times I've seen React libraries that extend the jsx properties of an element using it as an object field (at least it looks like this). I recently came across another library with a similar implementation - framer motion. The point is that if I want to add animation to my element, I must add a `motion` object to my jsx element, as a result, its will be looks like this - `<motion.span> text </motion.span>`

Actually the question. Could you explain to me how it works? Is this a simmilar to higher-order component?

Comment: It's most likely that `motion` is an object that contains a property called `span` whose value is a React component class/function/etc. More concretely, Babel translates some sample JSX `<Test>...</Test>` into the plain JS `React.createElement(Test, …)`. In this case, it transforms `<motion.span>…</motion.span>` into `React.createElement(motion.span, …)`. Some libraries do this simply as an organizational technique.

Comment: Thanks fot the response @AndrewLi ! I am not sure because I can pass motion to any component returning a dom element. For example, I can use it with a Material-ui `Grid` component like this <motion.Grid>. I doubt Framer knows about this component. If I understand you correctly

Comment: Interesting, I've never used Framer Motion before, but looks like Framer allows third-parties to create custom components with "packages". Material-UI has one: https://packages.framer.com/package/material-ui/material-ui -- these custom components are then attached to the `motion` object for you to use (that is how Motion "knows about" Grid). For reference, this is where it occurs in the source code: https://github.com/framer/motion/blob/main/src/render/dom/index.ts#L92

Comment: Are you asking about Compound Components? This appears to be what you are referring to. Have you checked the source code of the specific library you mention to see how they implement it?

Comment: Hello @DrewReese ! Yes, i have. But my experience with react is not too large and this is looks not clear to me